# Why this weird MYSQL result in division?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query like:

```
UPDATE t_example 
SET column1=column2/column3 
where 'SOME CLAUSE'
```

Suppose column2 has value 7 and column3 has value 1, the column1 should be set to value 7 after this statement but its always 6 instead of 7.  The result is always less by 1 for any pair of values where divisor is 1. I haven't checked for values other than 1 but why this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

#### This is probably a *floating-point* inaccuracy.

Your `column2` is probably a floating point and `column1` is an `int`. If the outcome of the calculation is `6.999999999` then the result converted to `int` is `6`.

If you need exact accuracy then you should use a *fixed-point* data type [like `decimal`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html).

Comment: but both are `integer` with length 11

Comment: And what is `column3`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. [See  here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d18d1/1). Can you provide a SQLFiddle that produces the problem you have?

Comment: hey check my question edit. The statement was an `update` statement and not insert. `column1` was initially holding value 0. Other columns hold 7 and 1 as before. Try this in Fiddle I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Ok i did it with SQLFiddle and it seems to be giving correct result . I dont know why mine is behaving as it is.

Comment: Do you have a trigger running on your table? WHat version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: No triggers. Version is 5.6.13

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function from MYSQL as follows

> NSERT INTO t_example SET column1=ROUND(column2/column3)